# Rellenar espacio vacío en un ConstrantLayout en JetpackCompose

Tags: android, jetpack-compose

Estoy probando el ConstrantLayout en Jetpack compose pero me atasco en un punto, necesitaría saber como hacer que el útlimo BOX ocupase toda la parte libre de la pantalla (fondo verde):

He probado con wrapContent, con fillMaxHeight, ... pero no logro encontrar la solución.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        val (a, b, c) = createRefs()

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .constrainAs(a) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
            .height(200.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {}

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .constrainAs(b) {
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
            }) {}

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Green)
            .constrainAs(c) {
                top.linkTo(a.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                bottom.linkTo(b.top)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
            .wrapContentSize()
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola en el box c(verde) dentro del ConstrainScope coloca `height = Dimension.fillToConstraints` que es una medición que hace coincidir con los constraints en este caso sería coincidir la altura en el top de c(verde) en el bottom de a(amarillo) y el bottom de c(verde) en el top de b(rojo) luego afuera en las propiedades del Modifier agrega la propiedad `.fillMaxWidth()` para que el box c(verde) ocupe todo el ancho de la pantalla.

Este es el código final.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        val (a, b, c) = createRefs()

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .constrainAs(a) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
            .height(200.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {}

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .constrainAs(b) {
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
            }) {}

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Green)
            .constrainAs(c) {
                top.linkTo(a.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                bottom.linkTo(b.top)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            }
            .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Te dejo un pantallazo de como queda la solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]